# How to duplicate a custom control (panel) programmatically

Tags: winforms, custom-controls, custom-component

I am using C# in VS 2010. I created a custom panel and would like to add this custom panel 9 times so I created a loop to add a copy of the panel 9 times at equal distance from each other. Each panel will have its own text and image. All I'm getting though is a single panel. Any insight would be appreciated

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int index = 0;
    List<CutePanel.CustomPanel> MenuItems = new List<CutePanel.CustomPanel>(); 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            this.cpTest.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
            this.cpTest.LabelText = "My super click text";
            this.cpTest.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12+(64*i));
            this.cpTest.Name = "cpTest";
            this.cpTest.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(344, 58);
            this.cpTest.SuperClick = null;
            this.cpTest.TabIndex = 6;
        }

        cpTest.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(cpTest_MouseClick);
        cpTest.SuperClick += new EventHandler(cpTest_SuperClick);
        cpTest.LabelText = "This is my text.";
        MenuItems.Add(cpTest);

    }

    void cpTest_SuperClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tcTest.SelectedIndex = index++ % 2;
    }

    void cpTest_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        tcTest.SelectedIndex = index++ % 2;
    }

    private void customPanel3_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        tcTest.SelectedIndex = index++ % 2;
    }



}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a distinction between your panel class and panel objects, also called instances of this class. Think of the class as a template that serves in creating objects. These objects are created with the `new` keyword:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    var cp = new CutePanel.CustomPanel();
    cp.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
    cp.LabelText = "My super click text";
    cp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12+(64*i));
    cp.Name = "cpTest" + i;
    cp.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(344, 58);
    cp.SuperClick = null;
    cp.TabIndex = 6;

    cp.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(cpTest_MouseClick);
    cp.SuperClick += new EventHandler(cpTest_SuperClick);

    cp.LabelText = "This is my text.";
    MenuItems.Add(cp);
}
```

You can also assign it values from the existing panel:

```
cp.BackColor = cpTest.BackColor;
cp.Size = cpTest.Size;
...
```

An elegant way of making a duplicate is to include a `Clone` method in your panel class

```
public class CustomPanel
{
    ...

    public CustomPanel Clone()
    {
        var cp = (CustomPanel)this.MemberwiseClone();
        cp.Parent = null; // It has not yet been added to the form.
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Then

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    CustomPanel cp = cpTest.Clone();

    // Now only change the differing properties
    cp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12+(64*i));
    cp.Name = "cpTest" + i;
    cp.TabIndex += i + 1;

    MenuItems.Add(cp);
}
```

**but attention:** If the cloned control is a container control containing other controls, you must clones those recursively as well. I.e., you must perform a deep clone! Creating new controls as shown in my first code snippet is safer.

Comment: I have just wasted about an hour trying to get your clone code to work. Did you test it?

Comment: I cannot test it as I don't have the definition of `CutePanel.CustomPanel` and other controls that are on this form. But the code has to be adapted your actual case anyway. Apparently it works for the OP. Be careful with cloning controls. Use the first method with preference.

Comment: By adapted, do you mean deleted? I have tried it. It does not work. I then looked up MemberwiseClone, it is a shallow clone. This explains why it does not work.

Comment: No. By adapted I mean that this code works only for the form of the OP (Tatiana Laurent). You must change it to work for your form. But as I said, creating new controls is better than cloning. If the control is a container control you must clone the nested controls as well.