# Programmatically copy X number of panels within Form

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I searched other SO articles but couldn't find a solution that works in my case.

My objective is to take a copy of `panel1`, which I have already created and formatted within `Form1` and duplicate it on the `Form1` n number of times.

I would like to space them out a given vertical distance as well. Below is the code I am using, it compiles without error however when I open my form it is not showing anything other than the original panel I manually created.

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int x = 100;
        this.Controls.Add(panel1);
        panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, x);
        x += 200;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have updated the code based on suggestions below but is still not working.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int y = 450;
        for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
        {
            Panel panel2 = new Panel();
            //Set Properties
            panel2.Controls.Add(this.button10);
            panel2.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, y);
            panel2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 5, 4, 5);
            panel2.Name = "panel" + i;
            panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(2754, 279);
            panel2.TabIndex = 0;
            y += 300;
            this.Controls.Add(panel2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cant just add the same panel again. You need to create a new panel, clone it from panel1 and add it to controls.

Comment: @Palle Due Due can you give me insight on how to achieve this? Not sure how to clone

Comment: See [How to duplicate a control (panel) programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18922419/205233)

Comment: @jbroutier take a look at the linked post - it specifically addresses your problem of also duplicating controls contained in your initial Panel.

Comment: Cloning is no easy feat, that's why I didn't post an answer. You can look at the link @Filburt posted. But it looks to me like you want to clone the panel with child controls, in that case you are better of making a user control.

Comment: @Filburt I am going to have to take some time to unpack the article you linked. I do not have a class setup as the OP in that question does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int x = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
        this.Controls.Add(uc1);
        uc1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, x);
        x += 200;
    }
```

Firstly, you have to move the line `int x = 100;` out of the loop, or it will position every panel at the same coordinate.
Secondly, you can't add the same component multiple times, so I recommend creating a UserControl which you can then instantiate.
As a last note, I wanted to add that the variable `x` is used for the Y-Coordinate(I don't know whether that's intentional).

Comment: Thanks, I had to go the UserControl route like you suggested.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are not duplicating the panel control. You are just adding the same object multiple times and then setting the location on the same object.

```
Panel panelToAdd = new Panel();
panelToAdd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, x);
//Set whatever properties you want
this.Controls.Add(panelToAdd);
```